# JSON Infinite Recursion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use @JsonManageReference and @JsonBackRefence to avoid infinite recursion in a one To Many Relationship. When I run Postman, the foreign key of the parent does not display in the list of the many side,   But i need to use that foreign Id one an Angular app. how can you help?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass by a DTO object and map the needed attributes in the front app.

Example: you have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private Long id ;
    private String x ;
    @ManyToOne
    private B b ;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    private Long id ;
    private String y ;
    @OneToMany(mappedby="b")
    private List<A> aListe ;
}
```

You should create a DTO :

```
public class ADTO {
    private Long id ;
    private String x ;
    private Long idB ;
}
```

and map the result from the db query to ADTO then return the DTO to the frontend.